# Expected declaration or statement at end of input - error

Tags: c

Can't compile the code is giving me an error in the last token "}" . Sorry the language but is a function to save into a binary file. The error is expected declaration or statement at end of input.

```
void gravarRegistos(contadorStruct *contador)
{
    char sair;
    int numelem = 0, erro = 0;
    FILE *ficheiro;

    do {
        printf("Deseja gravar as alteracoes? (S/N)\n");

        sair = lerCaracter();
        if (sair == 'S') {
            ficheiro = fopen("data.dat", "wb");

            if (ficheiro == NULL)
                printf("Falha a abrir o ficheiro\n");
            else {
                fwrite(contador, sizeof(contadorStruct),1, ficheiro);
                numelem = fwrite(veiculos, sizeof(veiculosStruct), 
                          contador->nrVeiculos, ficheiro);

                if (numelem != contador->nrVeiculos) {
                    printf("Ocorreu um erro a gravar os dados no ficheiro,
                            apenas gravou %d Carros", numelem);

                    erro = fclose(ficheiro);
                    if (erro)
                        printf("Erro %d a fechar o ficheiro", erro);
                }
            }
        }
    } while(sair != 'S' && sair !='N');
}
```

Comment: Please include the actual error message you're receiving in your post.

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you have posted. It's probably some other part of the code that you have not shown (where the compiler detects an error is not always the place which is the root cause of the error).

Comment: In particular, look for unbalanced braces (`{}`) or parentheses (`()`), and for missing semicolons (`;`) earlier in the file or hidden in a header.

Comment: I can't compile this code either. Why should I figure out what the complete C file should be? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: there are several other syntax errors in the code beyond the unexpected end of input error.  Suggest compiling with all warnings enabled, then fixing those warnings. (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: when use such lines as: `if (sair == 'S')`  it is always better to place the literal on the left side of the comparison operator, so the compiler can catch such an error as: `if (sair = 'S')` as those kinds of errors are very difficult to debug as the human eye slides right over the '=' and the brain thinks '=='

Comment: the returned code from all calls to `fwrite()` need to be checked, not just some of them.

Comment: regarding this line: `printf("Ocorreu um erro a gravar os dados no ficheiro,
                            apenas gravou %d Carros", numelem);`, this will result in the output having a large gap and a <newline> right in the middle of that gap.  A better method would be: `printf("%s%s%d &s", "Ocorreu um erro a gravar os dados no ficheiro",
                            "apenas gravou ", numelem, "Carros");`  or even better: `char string1[] = "Ocorreu um erro a gravar os dados no ficheiro, apenas gravou";   char string2[] = "Carros"   printf("%s %d %s:, string1, numelem, string2);

Answer (score 0):

the main problem with the code is the invalid syntax for the first parameter of the call to `printf()`.

a string ends at the `<newline>` unless escaped via `\`

Suggest:

```
printf("Ocorreu um erro a gravar os dados no ficheiro,\
                        apenas gravou %d Carros", numelem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's not a formatting articfact, it's likely to be this

```
printf("Ocorreu um erro a gravar os dados no ficheiro,
                            apenas gravou %d Carros", numelem);
```

You have a newline in your string constant here `... dados no ficheiro,` <--- that's confusing the compiler.

Not that there's errors in your code but I'd also adopt the "use braces even for single statements" approach.  Much easier to read and tell what's going on.